# I am trying to compile a program using cx freeze but with a redistribution package can anyone fix line 13

Tags: python, cx-freeze

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"
build_exe_options = {
"include_msvcr": True   #skip error msvcr100.dll missing
}
executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("Clock.pyw",base=base,icon="Icon.ico")]
cx_Freeze.setup(
    name= "Clock client",
    options = {"build_exe":  build_exe_options ,{"packages":["tkinter"],"include_files":["Icon.ico"]}},
    version = "0",
    description = "Clock program",
    executables = executables

    )
```

how is line 13 supposed to be formatted as when I try to compile this code I get the error invalid syntax with the curly bracket highlighted what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
options = {"build_exe":  build_exe_options ,{"packages":["tkinter"],"include_files":["Icon.ico"]}},
```

This code is wrong, because you shouldn't put the "build_exe_options ," bit.

Corrected:

```
options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter"],"include_files":["Icon.ico"]}},
```